# How to allow a day value by advancing the month in DateTimePicker

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Current date is for example 30 April 2020  - 30/4/20 but user wants to type 31/5/20.  But when '31' is typed '1' appears as of course there are only 30 Days in April

How might it be possible catch the type '31' and advance the month by 05 dynamically?  Is there an event which can catch the typed 31 before the dtp overrides and amends to 1

1) Catch what is typed before dtp amends
2) If day typed > max days in month THEN advance month by 1 (eg April to May)

Any ideas please?

Comment: I'm assuming this is a WinForms project.

Comment: There are different number of last days in each month, you need to specify them for all months (If Feb 29 given, then Feb + 1 is March - assuming it's not leap year, but not the same for March, 29th is not equal to Mar + 1 is April, etc.) It might be laborious a bit

Comment: Another approach would be to change the date portion order.  Have them select the month before the day, then there's no conflict as you're currently encountering.  Either have the dates as mm/dd/yy (common USA usage) or yy/mm/dd (probably makes more sense internationally?).

Comment: Yes and thank you.  i should have said this is a winform project.

Answer (score 0):

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Console.Title = "Type some Number from 0 to 31"
        Dim input_number As Integer
        input_number = Console.ReadLine
        If input_number > DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month) Then
            Dim newdate As String = Date.Now.AddMonths(1)
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
            Console.WriteLine(newdate)
        End If
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: This has no relation with the question.